# Why does getxattr fills extra elements?

Tags: c++, c

I have the below piece of code where I'm unable to figure out why I'm getting some weird symbols at the end of the buffer.

```
char value[100];
    if(getxattr(filename, "user.permission", value, sizeof(value))!=-1){
        //strncpy(val, value, strlen(value));
        printf("value is %s\n", value);
    }
```

For length >4 elements, it prints properly but if the value has less than four elements it appends some random characters at the end.

When I print the size of the value, it shows 6 for any value length between 1-4.
Please, someone, explain why is this behavior.

Comment: Please read [tag:c] and [tag:c++] and then delete the one that's not appropriate. That said, `getxattr()` is not standard C but comes from a certain environment, have you checked the according documentation? Also, add the according tag while you're at it!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt your links are to the complete list of newest questions for c and c++, respectively. I hope OP is not reading all of it before coming back ;P. Sorry, no trolling, just wanted to know if you actually wanted to link to the tag description, maybe?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) is a better link imho

Comment: I was targetting the tag description, which is on top of the two.

Comment: However, the problem as well as the solution is exactly the same for both languages, so why decide for one? Remember, Q&A here are not only for the OP (some say not even primarily).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to honour the *real* size of the attribute.

The call `getxattr()` returns the size of the value. So the following would be correct:

```
ssize_t sz = getxattr(filename, "user.permission", value, sizeof(value)-1);
if (sz != -1) {
    value[sz] = '\0';
    printf("value is %s\n", value);
}
```

It looks, like your value is a string, but it is not null terminated, you have to do that yourself. So, `getxattr()` is not appending random bytes, the char array is simply not initialized and it is not completely overwritten, so some uninitialized bytes remain there.

Comment: I suggest filing a report on the documentation of `getxattr` as it is not made explicit that the value returned is not null-terminated.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie My manpage states: "An extended attribute name is a simple NULL-terminated string.  The name includes a namespace prefix - there may be several, disjoint namespaces  associated  with  an  individual inode.  The value of an extended attribute is a chunk of arbitrary textual or binary data of specified length." <- Since binary data is mentioned, I would not expect it to be NULL-terminated, but it would be safer if they stated it more explicitly, agreed.

Comment: If it is binary data it could also contain a null in the middle, meaning it cannot "safely" be printed via printf, no?

Comment: @user463035818 Well, it _can_ be binary data... The user namespace is custom, I assume, that the OP knows, that printable ascii text is stored in the attribute user.permission.

Comment: @Ctx ok, I have to admit other than reading a bit of documentation I dont know anything about `getxattr`. My guess is that this is the reason why the function call does not place the null

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, you are correct, in general binary data is set, this is why no null termination is performed by getxattr(). But if you know, that the specific user attribute contains a string, you can of course printf() it after null termination is ensured

Comment: thanks for the clarification, assuming not having a null in the middle of a buffer once bite my ass, and now I am a bit paranoic about it ;)

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getxattr.2.html) (emphasize mine):

> getxattr() retrieves the value of the extended attribute identified
>          by name and associated with the given path in the filesystem.  The
>          attribute value is placed in the buffer pointed to by value; size
>          specifies the size of that buffer.  **The return value of the call is
>          the number of bytes placed in value.**

I didnt find something about `getxattr()` placing a `\0` so I would expect that you have to use the size returned from the function to know the size of the string.

Comment: Nice that it returns the size, but I would expect a function handling a string to null-terminate said string. And if it doesn't that it is then noted in the remarks or description.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i guess the reasoning is that the bytes can contain a 0 (also at a different position than the end) Note that it doesnt say string but the documentation only talks about raw bytes